# How to bind enum options to DevExpress.RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, devexpress, razor

Example code:

```
   @Html.DevExpress().RadioButtonList(settings => {
            settings.Properties.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SEICCV.Web.Models.eTipoControle));
            settings.Name = "radio";
   }).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().RadioGroupFor(m=>m.eTipoControleValue)
.DataSource(Html.GetEnumSelectList<SEICCV.Web.Models.eTipoControle>().Select(i => new { Value = short.Parse(i.Value), Text = i.Text.Value }))
                        .ValueExpr("Value")
                        .DisplayExpr("Text")
                        .Value(Model.eTipoControleValue)
                        .Layout(Orientation.Horizontal))
```